# run PowerShell script from CMD (tricky one)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-line

I know this may sound like a question that was here before (and partially it will be true).
Yet i have an interesting twist here.

**Needed flow:**
run Powershell script from CMD.
Seems trivial, and is actually working, with passing parameters etc...
But ...
My powershell script has a **Start-Job** with in it, as i want it to run async.

```
#######################################################################

   #$DropLocation = "SOME UNC PATH"
   #$buildid = "SOME VERSION"
param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$DropLocation,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$buildid
       ) 


Start-Job -Name Upload `
-ScriptBlock {

param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$DropLocation,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$buildid
       ) 
Write-Output "asd"
$buildpath = $DropLocation+"\"+$buildid
$logs = gci $buildpath"\logs" -Name "ActivityLog.AgentScope*.xml"

#Start-Sleep -Seconds 300

if ($logs.PSPath -gt 0)
    { 
        $destination = $env:TEMP+"\Config\"
        Copy-Item $logs.PSPath "$destination $buildid.xml"
    }
} `
-ArgumentList $DropLocation,$buildid

#######################################################################
```

I am using Param to intake from outside, and then once again in the Start-Job so that the Async job get its params

This script is saved as **SCRIPTNAME.ps1** and i am trying to run it from CMD.

**From cmd** (running as admin)

```
powershell "& "C:\temp\SCRIPTNAME.ps1" "SOME UNC PATH" "SOME VERSION""
```

or

```
powershell -file "C:\temp\SCRIPTNAME.ps1" "SOME UNC PATH" "SOME VERSION"
```

Nothing happens.
Yet from the **PowerShell ISE** all is working well

Assistance is more than appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `cd C:\location of ps.1` and running `.\thefile.ps1` ?

Comment: You would have to escape the embedded `"` in the first command as `\"`. The second command looks correct (and is the better choice). When you say that nothing happens, can you be more specific? No error message? Is the script invoked at all?

Comment: Hey,
I am expecting a file to be copied to a specific location, well that is not happening.
Whereas when running from Powershell ISE same plot of the PS1 script it works fine...
I feel that there is something that i may be missing during the Invocation from CMD

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me this error:
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Argumentlist'

Comment: Did you try dot sourcing? `powershell -noexit ". C:\temp\SCRIPTNAME.ps1"` Let me know if that works and I'll post as an answer. I'm thinking how you are launching the script is making it run single threaded and that might be causing the issue.

Comment: Hmmmmm! first run, i am seeing results !
Gonna try it on test environment as part of a build invocation ^_^

Comment: Great, good to hear. I went ahead and added it as an answer with a brief explanation of why this works.

Comment: Did you get it working in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`powershell -noexit ". C:\temp\SCRIPTNAME.ps1"`

Dot source it, this will change the scope of the sourced function for your job to work within the currently running script's scope while allowing you to run multiple threads also.

Comment: Will test in 7 hours

Comment: The dot, in the ". C:\ ..." is not doing anything.
Its the -noexit parameter that makes it happen.
Either way, you've got us the solution !

Comment: ny the way, this is working on Windows 10, but its not on Win Server 2016.....

Answer (score 0):

My take on your issue, based on the provided script, is that your script exit before the job completion.

--

Here's both behavior side-to-side

**ISE / VSCode**

- Script is launched
- Start-Job is called
- Script complete
- Job complete

**CMD**

- Script is launched through cmd
- Start-Job is called
- Script complete
- Powershell session is terminated (and job execution killed)
- Job never complete

To prevent the session from being killed until the job complete, add the following line at the end of your script `Receive-Job -Name 'upload' -Wait`

Here's the new script with that modification.

```
#######################################################################

   #$DropLocation = "SOME UNC PATH"
   #$buildid = "SOME VERSION"
param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$DropLocation,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$buildid
       ) 


Start-Job -Name Upload `
-ScriptBlock {

param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$DropLocation,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$buildid
       ) 
Write-Output "asd"
$buildpath = $DropLocation+"\"+$buildid
$logs = gci $buildpath"\logs" -Name "ActivityLog.AgentScope*.xml"

#Start-Sleep -Seconds 300

if ($logs.PSPath -gt 0)
    { 
        $destination = $env:TEMP+"\Config\"
        Copy-Item $logs.PSPath "$destination $buildid.xml"
    }
} `
-ArgumentList $DropLocation,$buildid

# Prevent the session to be killed before the job return.
Receive-Job -Name 'upload' -Wait 
#######################################################################
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, i am intentionally running Start-Job because i need it to be asynch (i dont want to wait for it).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the Profile / Policy configuration of the environment, Might I suggest Invoking with the profile / policy modifiers in the example below? Sometimes they can make all the difference to executing powershell from batch

Have you tried writing generating and executing the powershell script from within Batch

Whenever I need powershell to do something cmd can't, I write the script as a function I can call from within the batch file.

Here's an example of my approach:

```
:createshortcut
(
ECHO # Create a Shortcut with Windows PowerShell
ECHO $SourceFileLocation = "%ShortcutTargetPATH%"
ECHO $ShortcutLocation = "%userprofile%\Desktop\%shortcutname%.Ink"
ECHO #New-Object : Creates an instance of a Microsoft .NET Framework or COM object.
ECHO #-ComObject WScript.Shell: This creates an instance of the COM object that             
represents the WScript.Shell for invoke CreateShortCut
ECHO $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
ECHO $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutLocation^)
ECHO $Shortcut.TargetPath = $SourceFileLocation
ECHO $Shortcut.IconLocation = "%IconPATH%\%IconNameEXT%"
ECHO #Save the Shortcut to the TargetPath
ECHO $Shortcut.Save(^)
) >%AppDataPATH%\%PowerShellnameEXT%

TIMEOUT 1 >nul

Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %AppDataPATH%\%PowerShellnameEXT%

TIMEOUT 1 >nul

DEL /Q "%AppDataPATH%\%PowerShellnameEXT%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Set the values required for the scripts execution & then Just call the Function. The key thing to remember when using this approach is to Escape the appropriate characters when writing the .ps1 file

Comment: Hey,
This is actually an interesting approach, yet the problem is that while using Start-Job, it seems to be not doing anything, even if the script is working good by itself (wihtout deleting it as you've mentioned).
Please do try to simulate my script, that was presented in the issue desription.

Comment: Has the line
#Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
been remarked out for a reason?

And have you tried with
powershell.exe as opposed to just powershell as you've shown in the question?

Comment: The remarked Start-Sleep will be used during an actual run, was outted so that script wont hold for 5 minutes..
I have tried powershell.exe and powershell...